# django - Single User object can store multiple objects of model

Tags: python, django

I am making a django app where a User can have multiple urls stored in his account .The problem, I am facing is a Single User is able to store a single url ,on adding multiple it gives a Integrity error.
**So how can i add Multiple url to a single User object**

**models.py**

```
class Userprofile(models.Model):
    user        = models.OneToOneField(User)    
    url         = models.CharField(max_length = 100 ,)
    shortcode   = models.CharField(max_length = 10 ,blank = True)
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def save(self , *args , **kwargs):
        if self.shortcode is None or self.shortcode is '':
            self.shortcode = create_shortcode(self)
            super(Userprofile, self).save(*args , **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**forms.py**

```
class URLForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model    = Userprofile 
       fields   = ('url',)
       widgets={
       'url':forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Long URL','class':'form-control'}),
            }

    def clean_url(self):
        url  = self.cleaned_data['url']
        url_validator = URLValidator()
    try:
        url_validator(url)
    except:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Enter a proper URL ')
    return url
```

**Views.py**

```
def user_url_info(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = URLForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        # try:
        #   obj = Userprofile.objects.get(url = form.cleaned_data['url'])
        #   print('already')
        # except:
        obj = form.save(commit = False)
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.save()
        return render(request , 'detaail.html',{'obj':obj}) 
  else:
    form    = URLForm() 
return render(request , 'urlform.html' ,{'form':form})
```

so I want that a request.user can sore multiple object of Userprofile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a model for urls, connecting with a foreign key user id in the Url Model. Storing redundant data means the database is not normalized. Storing the data in this matter, normalized, makes best use of Django's Object Relational Model.

Answer (score 0):

You can make url field as foreignkey and make a new model to store only url

```
class UserURL(models.Model):    
    url = models.CharField(max_length = 100 ,)



class Userprofile(models.Model):
    user        = models.OneToOneField(User)    
    url         = models.Foreignkey(UserURL)
    shortcode   = models.CharField(max_length = 10 ,blank = True)
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to relate a user to multiple urls, you should not do OneToOne fields.

```
class UserUrlRelationship(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(...)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

or

```
class Url(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(...)

class UserUrlRelationship(models.Model):
    url = models.ForeignKey(Url)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # This is literally what a ManyToManyField does in the background.
    # If you investigate the database, you will see extra tables that
    # represent your many to many fields. each entry is a relationship. Make sure that you
    # don't have unique constraints on these 2 fields via OneToManyFields,
    # OneToOneFields or unique=True.
```

Don't do OneToOne fields or else that restricts you so that one user maps to only one url and same thing the other way around (one url to only one user).